# Command block check chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a shop where the player must hold a item and then click a button, and what I want to do is a "test for" like command to check if the item in the players hand matches the item in slot 0 in the chest. Is there a way to do that thanks.

or I could just check if the item is in the players inventory.
:)

Comment: It seems this user found how to testfor the chest and posted a separate question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/233587/118457)

Comment: @Judge2020 your link is pointing to this question, you might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare the two items in the sense of

Chest == Hand

However you can do something more like

Chest == X and
Hand == X therefor
Chest == Hand

You can check what is in the hand using {SelectedItem:{Item Tag}} (see more at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot compare items in inventories.  You probably want to check for the specific item in the command.